# Problema con tabla de Bootstrap

Tags: html, bootstrap

Problema porque la tabla no se alinea bien. Por ejemplo, el botón para votar sale en "Port" y no está centrado en "Vote".

Imágen:
https://preview.ibb.co/cbFWFk/IMG_5055.jpg

Código PHP:

```
<div class="container">
   <!-- Errors -->
    <?php echo $error; ?>
   <!-- Errors -->
   <center><h2>Featured servers</h2><p>This is a list of our favorite and recommended servers to which you should join. To connect, you must download the Minecraft: PE app. If you want your server to appear here, you must <a href='/premium'>upgrade</a> to a premium plan.</p></center>
   <!-- Featured servers -->
   <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>IP Address<th>
        <th>Port</th>
        <th>Vote</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>survivaltimepe.leet.cc</td>
        <td>30598</td>
        <td><a class="btn btn-success" href="/vote">Vote for us <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></span></a></td>
      </tr>
      </tbody></table></div></div>
```

Comment: Ya te habían dicho que una de tus `th` no está cerrada. No tienes que duplicar las preguntas.

Answer (score 1):

En en código tienes una etiqueta  sin cerrar. Cuando las tablas no se alinean correctamente suele ser por td,tr o th no cerrados correctamente. Quedaría:

```
    <tr>
      <th>IP Address</th>
      <th>Port</th>
      <th>Vote</th>
    </tr>
```

De todas maneras la imagen que pones no se corresponde con el código que nos aportas.